# x86 simple mov instruction

Tags: x86, att, mov

This is a simple question but I can't find reliable answers on google.

What does this instruction mean:

```
movl %eax, (%esi, %ecx, 4)
```

Is it move the value at register `eax` to the value in memory that `(%esi, %ecx, 4)` is pointing too?

`(%esi, %ecx, 4)` is for an array. So it means Array[Xs + 4i] where Xs is the starting point in memory for the Array and i is just an offset in the integer array.

Comment: Just one thing: the code does not imply that eax represents an integer arrays. It could be a vector of pointers. Otherwise, yes: source first, destination second. Always confusing since Intel/Microsoft do it the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly correct.  This is AT&T syntax, so the source comes first, then the destination.  Thus, it stores the contents of the `eax` register to the memory location `esi + 4*ecx`.

If you like to think of this as an array, it stores `eax` to the `ecx`th entry of an array of 4-byte objects based at `esi`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly what it is. In AT&T syntax, memory addressing is written as:

```
offset(base, index, multiplier)
```

`offset` is a signed constant specifying the offset from `base`, `base` is a register of where to start at, `index` is the register specifying how far after the start of the array to look, after multiplying by `multiplier`, which can be 1, 2, 4, or 8.

You must specify at least one of `offset`, `base`, and `index`. To use `index` without `base`, you need to precede it with a comma ( `(, index)` ). If you don't specify `multiplier`, it defaults to 1.

In Intel syntax, this is written as:

```
[base + index*multiplier + offset]
```

This is easier to understand, since it is simply a math problem.