# Assembly move instructions

Tags: assembly, x86

Hi I just started learning assembly in IA32. Can anyone tell me what these two move instructions do? They seem to be some compound instruction.

```
movl    (%esi,%edx), %ebx
movl    %ebx, (%edi,%edx)
```

Comment: Thats AT&T syntax for memory references. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518448/x86-simple-mov-instruction-help) for help interpretting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
movl    (%esi,%edx), %ebx
```

Here you have an array whose base is at `%edx`. You are accessing an element indexed by `%esi`, and moving it to a temporary register `%ebx`.

```
movl    %ebx, (%edi,%edx)
```

Here you are moving a value from your temporary register `%ebx` to an element in your `%edx` array indexed by `%edi`.